# Microsoft Report Viewer Login Failed

Tags: vb.net

I'm building an asp.net web application using Microsoft report viewer.  It connects to a SQL database using integrated security.  However when I first load the report page after it has been published to the server (everything works fine locally), I get this error:

```
    An error has occurred during report processing.
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Login failed for user 'SERVER NAME REMOVED'.
```

The weird thing is that when I click the refresh button on the report (not IE's refresh button), it loads just fine.  I know that login will not work for the database server, but why is the report viewer not using the integrated security I set in the web.config?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `IReportServerCredentials` inteface, see the implementation below:

```
 public class CustomReportCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
    {
        protected string _username = string.Empty;
        protected string _password = string.Empty;
        protected string _domainName = string.Empty;

        public CustomReportCredentials(string userName, string password, string domainName)
        {
            _username = userName;
            _password = password;
            _domainName = domainName;
        }
        public bool GetFormsCredentials(out System.Net.Cookie authCookie, out string userName, out string password, out string authority)
        {
            authCookie = null;
            userName = password = authority = null;
            return false;
        }

        public System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        public System.Net.ICredentials NetworkCredentials
        {
            get
            {
                if (_username != "noadmin")
                {
                    return new NetworkCredential(_username, _password, _domainName);
                }
                else
                {
                    Uri uri = new Uri("http://tempuri.org/");
                    ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                    NetworkCredential credential = credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
                    return credential;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can set report viewer credential property to `IReportServerCredentials`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
if (!Page.IsPostBack){
IReportServerCredentials iReportCredentials = new CustomReportCredentials("user",
                    "mypassword", "mydomain");
                ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = iReportCredentials;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this must be what I missed.  Is there a way to make this use integrated security instead of me having to set a username/password?